# Error while running move_group.launch

Tags: ros, moveit, moveit-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am created moveit config .. and while I running move_group.launch I got the following errors. Can you please point out what may be the issue

```
... logging to /home/geek/.ros/log/54b82542-2fd1-11e3-abe0-0c6076593c99/roslaunch-        geek-Inspiron-1545-30831.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://geek-Inspiron-1545:44739/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /move_group/allow_trajectory_execution
 * /move_group/capabilities
 * /move_group/controller_list
 * /move_group/elite_arm/kinematics_solver
 * /move_group/elite_arm/kinematics_solver_attempts
 * /move_group/elite_arm/kinematics_solver_search_resolution
 * /move_group/elite_arm/kinematics_solver_timeout
 * /move_group/elite_arm/longest_valid_segment_fraction
 * /move_group/elite_arm/planner_configs
 * /move_group/elite_arm/projection_evaluator
 * /move_group/gripper/longest_valid_segment_fraction
 * /move_group/gripper/planner_configs
 * /move_group/gripper/projection_evaluator
 * /move_group/jiggle_fraction
 * /move_group/max_safe_path_cost
 * /move_group/moveit_controller_manager
 * /move_group/moveit_manage_controllers
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/type
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ESTkConfigDefault/type
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/type
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECEkConfigDefault/type
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRMkConfigDefault/type
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRMstarkConfigDefault/type
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTConnectkConfigDefault/type
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTkConfigDefault/type
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstarkConfigDefault/type
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SBLkConfigDefault/type
 * /move_group/planning_plugin
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_geometry_updates
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_planning_scene
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_state_updates
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_transforms_updates
 * /move_group/request_adapters
 * /move_group/start_state_max_bounds_error
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint1/has_acceleration_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint1/has_velocity_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint1/max_acceleration
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint1/max_velocity
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint2/has_acceleration_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint2/has_velocity_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint2/max_acceleration
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint2/max_velocity
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint3/has_acceleration_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint3/has_velocity_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint3/max_acceleration
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint3/max_velocity
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint4/has_acceleration_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint4/has_velocity_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint4/max_acceleration
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint4/max_velocity
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint5/has_acceleration_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint5/has_velocity_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint5/max_acceleration
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint5/max_velocity
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint6/has_acceleration_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint6/has_velocity_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint6/max_acceleration
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint6/max_velocity
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint7/has_acceleration_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint7/has_velocity_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint7/max_acceleration
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint7/max_velocity
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint8/has_acceleration_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint8/has_velocity_limits
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint8/max_acceleration
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint8/max_velocity
 * /robot_description_semantic
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    move_group (moveit_ros_move_group/move_group)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[move_group-1]: started with pid [30849]
[ INFO] [1381216345.557748471]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[ INFO] [1381216348.841237661]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[ INFO] [1381216350.168010014]: Publishing maintained planning scene on     'monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1381216350.178695310]: MoveGroup debug mode is OFF
[ INFO] [1381216350.471018656]: Initializing OMPL interface using ROS parameters
[ INFO] [1381216350.552689519]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
[ INFO] [1381216350.788519576]: Param 'default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using     default value: 10
[ INFO] [1381216350.790059508]: Param 'start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.1
[ INFO] [1381216350.791632544]: Param 'start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using     default value: 0.5
[ INFO] [1381216350.793167097]: Param 'start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.5
[ INFO] [1381216350.794511191]: Param 'jiggle_fraction' was set to 0.05
[ INFO] [1381216350.795916955]: Param 'max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[ INFO] [1381216350.796061317]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Parameterization'
[ INFO] [1381216350.796108110]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[ INFO] [1381216350.796150783]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[ INFO] [1381216350.796186682]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[ INFO] [1381216350.796227050]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[FATAL] [1381216350.922118691]: Exception while loading controller manager     'simple_moveit_controller_manager/SimpleMoveItControllerManager': According to the     loaded plugin descriptions the class     simple_moveit_controller_manager/SimpleMoveItControllerManager with base class type     moveit_controller_manager::MoveItControllerManager does not exist. Declared types are      moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager     pr2_moveit_controller_manager/Pr2MoveItControllerManager
[ INFO] [1381216350.944767941]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
[ INFO] [1381216351.363981581]: 
********************************************************
* MoveGroup using: 
*     - CartesianPathService
*     - ExecutePathService
*     - KinematicsService
*     - MoveAction
*     - PickPlaceAction
*     - MotionPlanService
*     - QueryPlannersService
*     - StateValidationService
********************************************************

[ INFO] [1381216351.364122661]: Starting scene monitor
[ INFO] [1381216351.366339285]: Listening to 'planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1381216351.366685908]: Starting world geometry monitor
[ INFO] [1381216351.369412023]: Listening to 'collision_object' using message notifier     with target frame '/base_link '
[ INFO] [1381216351.375673993]: Listening to 'collision_map' using message notifier with target frame '/base_link '
[ INFO] [1381216351.378368120]: Listening to 'planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[ WARN] [1381216351.379922925]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[ INFO] [1381216353.371930570]: Listening to 'attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[ INFO] [1381216353.372241783]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[ INFO] [1381216353.372715446]: MoveGroup context initialization complete

All is well! Everyone is happy! You can start planning now!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88466/error-while-running-move_group.launch/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is:

```
'simple_moveit_controller_manager/SimpleMoveItControllerManager': According to the     loaded plugin descriptions the class     simple_moveit_controller_manager/SimpleMoveItControllerManager with base class type     moveit_controller_manager::MoveItControllerManager does not exist. Declared types are      moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager     pr2_moveit_controller_manager/Pr2MoveItControllerManager
```

From what I can see is that you ask for simple_moveit_controller_manager/SimpleMoveItControllerManager, but the name you are looking for is  moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager.

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1